# How to retrieve Directories size including all sub-directories?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have stored images from the net like this

```
Documents/imagecache/domain1/original/path/inURI/foo.png
Documents/imagecache/domain2/original/path/inURI/bar.png
Documents/imagecache/...
Documents/imagecache/...
```

Now I'd like to check the size of `imagecache` including all it sub-directories.

Is there a convenient way of doing it — preferable without crawling through all the data manually?

**edit**

I want to check the size inside an iPhone App. jailbreaking is no option.

## Solution

derived from Nikolai's answer

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *p = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
unsigned long long x =0 ;
for (NSString *s in [fileMgr subpathsAtPath:p]) {
    NSDictionary *attributes = [fileMgr attributesOfItemAtPath: [p stringByAppendingPathComponent:s] error:NULL];
    x+=[attributes fileSize];
}
```

Comment: Response to close-vote: this question doesn't belong to superuser.com, as it is a valid programming question. it must be done in obj-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is not stored in the filesystem. There's no way to get the combined size without traversing the directories.

I’m not aware of a library function that does that but here's a quick hack that should work:

```
unsigned long long combinedSize = 0;
for (NSString* path in [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsAtPath:myDir]) {
    combinedSize += [[attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:NULL] fileSize];
}
```

**Edit 2015:**

I added a much more comprehensive (and more correct) answer to [a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28660040/104790).