# Device free space and sandbox space used

Tags: ios, ios4, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to get the free space on the device and the amount of space my sandbox is using. Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Rick

Comment: Still looking for some help... I've tried:
NSFileManager.SystemFreeSize.Length but get some nonsense (20)
and
DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
d.AvailableFreeSpace;
But this crashed the app and I'm told by MonoTouch that the API is not supported. 

Why is it so frigg'n difficult to get the free space on the device????

Comment: Still looking for an answer on how to get total free space on the device - Any updates from MonoTouch?

Answer (score 6):

In Objective-C you can get the available file system space with `NSFileManager`:

```
NSFileManager* filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];            

NSDictionary* fsAttr = [filemgr attributesOfFileSystemForPath:docDirectory error:NULL];

unsigned long long freeSize = [(NSNumber*)[fsAttr objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize] unsignedLongLongValue];
```

To get the amount of space your app is using read this question:
[Calculate the size of a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188469/calculate-the-size-of-a-folder)

Answer (score 0):

this is close, but not perfect.

```
NSFileManager a = NSFileManager.DefaultManager;
NSError _error;

string _databaseFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "..");
NSDictionary _b =  a.GetFileSystemAttributes(_databaseFolder,out _error);
NSObject _d =  NSObject.FromObject("NSFileSystemFreeSize");
NSObject _c =  _b.ObjectForKey(_d);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the direct translate from @phix23 to MonoTouch (Sorry for the length of the lines, cocoa is too verbose):

```
var docDir = NSSearchPath.GetDirectories(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory,NSSearchPathDomain.User, true)[0];
var freeSpace = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetFileSystemAttributes(docDir).FreeSize;
```