# Get the used space, free space on iPhone programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect total available/free disk space on the iPhone/iPad device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712527/how-to-detect-total-available-free-disk-space-on-the-iphone-ipad-device)

I  would like to get the following details of an iOS device in an iOS app. I have searched in Google, but I didn't get any ideas for these:

1. Formatted Space
2. Used Space
3. Free Space

Comment: This may help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124308/device-free-space-and-sandbox-space-used

Comment: @H2CO3: I wonder... can we do this in sandbox-ed app?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya why not? This uses the POSIX layer.

Answer (score 1):

make C system call to statfs.

see: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/statfs.2.html

and this SO answer:
[check enough space on iphone device before downloading files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310445/check-enough-space-on-iphone-device-before-downloading-files)

Answer (score 1):

For total & Free spaces, this method will return freeSpace

```
- (uint64_t)freeDiskspace{
    uint64_t totalSpace = 0;
    uint64_t totalFreeSpace = 0;

    __autoreleasing NSError *error = nil;  
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[paths lastObject] error: &error];  

   if (dictionary) {  
       NSNumber *fileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemSize];  
       NSNumber *freeFileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];
      totalSpace = [fileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
      totalFreeSpace = [freeFileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
      NSLog(@"Memory Capacity of %llu MiB with %llu MiB Free memory available.", ((totalSpace/1024ll)/1024ll), ((totalFreeSpace/1024ll)/1024ll));
   }
   else {  
      NSLog(@"Error Obtaining System Memory Info: Domain = %@, Code = %d", [error domain], [error code]);  
   }  

   return totalFreeSpace;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get these using [uidevice-extension](https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension)
What you need are the following funcitons:

```
- (NSNumber *) totalDiskSpace;
- (NSNumber *) freeDiskSpace;
```

from UIDevice-Hardware.h

Answer (score 0):

You could also use NSFileManager and the method

```
- (NSDictionary *)attributesOfFileSystemForPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error
```

on the path where you would like to send data. This method uses statfs (mentioned in other answers).