# iphone - storing images to disk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, diskspace

I have a bunch of images that I want to save to my app but I'm worried about taking up too much space on the device.

Is there a way to check how much space I'm taking up?  And how do I know when I am taking up too much space and I have to delete some things?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually ended up using EGOImageLoading from Enormego.

[Blog post about it](http://developers.enormego.com/view/what_if_images_on_the_iphone_were_as_easy_as_html)

[Github link](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading)

It apparently downloads the images asynchronously, allows you to use a placeholder while waiting for the image to download, and caches the images so they're accesible offline.

Comment: Your question never stated that you were looking for an asynchronous image loading method.

Comment: I wasn't until I found it. It caches the images as well.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Calculate the size of a folder…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188469/calculate-the-size-of-a-folder), you'll find some ways to calculate the size of a folder. As far as I know there is no size limit to how much data you can save on the device. However if the device's disc is full saving data will fail.

Look at http://kdbdallas.com/2008/12/27/maciphone-show-availble-useable-diskspace/ on how to find out how much disk space is available.

You can also make use of NSFileManager's instance method [attributesOfFileSystemForPath:error:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW9). It returns a dictionary, have a look at [the keys, especially NSFileSystemFreeSize.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW1)

If you run out of space you should delete files of course, at least present the user some information on how much space the app is using up.