# iOS - Get sum of filesize in directory

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, directory, nsfilemanager

I have the following code I use to cache photos I load off Flickr in the device's memory:

```
NSURL *urlForPhoto = [FlickrFetcher urlForPhoto:self.photo format:FlickrPhotoFormatLarge];
NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imagePath = [rootPath stringByAppendingString:[self.photo objectForKey:FLICKR_PHOTO_ID]];
NSData *dataForPhoto;
NSError *error = nil;
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath]) {
    dataForPhoto = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
} else {
    dataForPhoto = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlForPhoto];
    [dataForPhoto writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
}
```

I want to limit this to 10MB and then if the limit is reached to remove the oldest photo in the cache, how can I get the total size of all the files I've saved and check which one is the oldest?

Comment: Yep, I have to make the comment longer so I can answer.

Comment: Calculating the size that a directory takes up on disk is actually a little more involved. Find out how to in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28660040/104790) to a similar question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the size of a file like so

```
NSError *attributesError = nil;

    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:URL error:&attributesError];

    int fileSize = [fileAttributes fileSize];
```

So you can maybe iterate through all the files in the folder and add up the file sizes...not sure if theres a direct way to get the directory size, also theres this SO post talking about this aswell, you can find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188469/calculate-the-size-of-a-folder)

To find the creation date of the file you can do

```
NSString *path = @"";
    NSDictionary* fileAttribs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil];
    NSDate *result = [fileAttribs valueForKey:NSFileCreationDate]; //or NSFileModificationDate
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Awesome Daniel, one more thing, how would be a sure way of checking if a directory exists? Because I'm gonna create a subdirectory in the documents directory if it doesn't exist

Comment: [NSFileManager defaultManager] itemExistsAtPath should do the trick

Comment: It's actually fileExistsAtPath, Daniel. Now, can you answer one more thing? If I get the attributes and get the NSFileSize object on it, I get a small number, if I call it on a file I get a large number (both in bytes I'm assuming), doesn't getting the file size for the directory give me the total of all files within it?

Comment: @8vius not sure as i have never tried that, but by your comment i guess  not?

Comment: It doesn't seem like it, so to be sure I'm just adding all the files, it's odd though, if you query for the size of a directory, its size should be the total size of its contents