# iOS recursive folder size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, file, size

I'm storing files in a local documents directory, separated by folders. **Is there an easy way for me to get the file size of the contents of the documents directory and all subdirectories on an iPhone?**

I can manually iterate over folders and keep adding file size, but I'm hoping there's something cleaner and more efficient.

Thank you !

Comment: Calculating the size that a directory takes up on disk is actually a little more involved. Find out how to in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28660040/104790) to a similar question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can recursively go over all folders and get the size.
Like this:

```
+(NSUInteger)getDirectoryFileSize:(NSURL *)directoryUrl
{
    NSUInteger result = 0;
    NSArray *properties = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: NSURLLocalizedNameKey,
                           NSURLCreationDateKey, NSURLLocalizedTypeDescriptionKey, nil];

    NSArray *array = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                      contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:directoryUrl
                      includingPropertiesForKeys:properties
                      options:(NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles)
                      error:nil];

    for (NSURL *fileSystemItem in array) {
        BOOL directory = NO;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[fileSystemItem path] isDirectory:&directory];
        if (!directory) {
            result += [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[fileSystemItem path] error:nil] objectForKey:NSFileSize] unsignedIntegerValue];
        }
        else {
            result += [CacheManager getDirectoryFileSize:fileSystemItem];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What is this 'CacheManager', I don't think it's an apple library?

Comment: Just replace "CacheManager" with the name of your own method file that contains this

Answer (score 5):

The approach and efficiency vary depends on the iOS version. For iOS 4.0 and later you can make a category on `NSFileManager` with something like this:

```
- (unsigned long long)contentSizeOfDirectoryAtURL:(NSURL *)directoryURL
{
    unsigned long long contentSize = 0;
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [self enumeratorAtURL:directoryURL includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLFileSizeKey] options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles errorHandler:NULL];
    NSNumber *value = nil;
    for (NSURL *itemURL in enumerator) {
        if ([itemURL getResourceValue:&value forKey:NSURLFileSizeKey error:NULL]) {
            contentSize += value.unsignedLongLongValue;
        }
    }
    return contentSize;
}
```