# NSFileSize what Entity?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have a method which gives me the fileSize of a directory.
I looked up in the Documentation but it's not declared which entity NSFileSize has.

Comment: What do you mean by entity? And can you provide a link to the documentation you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself, thanks to the hint that a directory has no FileSize.
Here is my completed Code:

```
-(float)getSizeOfDirectory:(NSString *)directory{

    NSFileManager *filemgr;
    NSArray *filelist;
    int count;
    float cacheSize = 0;

    filemgr =[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    filelist = [filemgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directory error:NULL];
    count = [filelist count];

    for (NSString *url in filelist) {
        NSData *data = [filemgr contentsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",directory,url]];
        cacheSize = cacheSize + ([data length]/1000);
    }

    cacheSize = (cacheSize/1024);
    NSLog(@"cacheSize: %f MB",cacheSize);

    return cacheSize;
}
```

Comment: This code is not only utterly wasteful but also incorrect. [In this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28660040/104790) I'm explaining why and how it could be done faster and more precisely.

Answer (score 5):

in [NSFileManager doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW2):

> NSFileSize
>
> The key in a file attribute dictionary whose value
> indicates the file's size in bytes. The corresponding value is an
> NSNumber object containing an unsigned long long. Important If the
> file has a resource fork, the returned value does not include the size
> of the resource fork. Available in iOS 2.0 and later. Declared in
> NSFileManager.h.

Comment: If it output my FileSize in the console it has a value of 25228 (bytes?) if I calculate the size in megabytes it outputs 25 228 bytes = 0.0240592957 megabytes but the directory in the Finder is 10MB large.

Comment: @btype As I said in my answer: There's no `NSFileSize` for directories. You have to explain what you do and post code that fails. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: well, i suppose that you get just the size of the folder (i mean the file used to store informations of the folder), and not the contents files size...

Answer (score 3):

`NSFileSize` is a key in attribute dictionaries as returned by `NSFileManager`'s `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:`. The object is an NSNumber from which you can get the POD value using `unsignedLongLongValue`.

You don't get `NSFileSize` for dictionaries. What method do you mean?