# Is there a way to detect used disk space for the application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, diskspace

I need to check if my application uses more than 300mb disk space. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2189216/1702077) to find the size of a folder

```
- (unsigned long long int)folderSize:(NSString *)folderPath {
    NSArray *filesArray = 
     [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:folderPath 
                                                         error:nil];
    NSEnumerator *filesEnumerator = [filesArray objectEnumerator];
    NSString *fileName;
    unsigned long long int fileSize = 0;

    while (fileName = [filesEnumerator nextObject]) {
     NSDictionary *fileDictionary = 
      [[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
        attributesOfItemAtPath:[folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName] 
                         error:nil];
        fileSize += [fileDictionary fileSize];
    }

    return fileSize;
}
```

Call this

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *documentsDirectory = 
 [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                      NSUserDomainMask, 
                                      YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *cachesDirectory = 
 [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, 
                                      NSUserDomainMask, 
                                      YES) objectAtIndex:0];

unsigned long long int bundleSize = [self folderSize:bundlePath];
unsigned long long int docsSize = [self folderSize:documentsDirectory];
unsigned long long int cachesSize = [self folderSize:cachesDirectory];

long double totalSize = (bundleSize + docsSize + cachesSize)/1024.0/1024.0;
```

This will give you the size of your app's bundle, documents directory, and caches directory in megabytes.